# Google Maps JavaScript API library must be loaded

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api

Hello guys I am new to `React` and I am using
**react-places-autocomplete** https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-places-autocomplete and facing the following `error`:

```js
Error: [react-places-autocomplete]: Google Maps JavaScript API library must be loaded. See: https://github.com/kenny-hibino/react-places-autocomplete#load-google-library**
```

My `html` includes the necessary `script` tag!

```html
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****************&libraries=places"></script>
```

Here is my Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*********&libraries=places"></script>
  <!-- bundle.js -->
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should load the `google maps library` before you mount any component!

```html
<!-- Maps library -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=*****************&libraries=places"></script>
<!-- bundle.js -->
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

You could try something like this in the `affected` component:

```js
state = {
  gmapsLoaded: false,
}

initMap = () => {
  this.setState({
    gmapsLoaded: true,
  })
}

componentDidMount () {
  window.initMap = this.initMap
  const gmapScriptEl = document.createElement(`script`)
  gmapScriptEl.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SECRET_EATING&libraries=places&callback=initMap`
  document.querySelector(`body`).insertAdjacentElement(`beforeend`, gmapScriptEl)
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.state.gmapsLoaded && (
        <PlacesAutocomplete />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The example is taken from [here](https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete/issues/195#issuecomment-382596430).

Comment: I have added this into index.html, getting same as well

Comment: is it loaded before `bundle.js`? The order matters! How does your `build` process look like? Could you provide your `index.html` example?

Comment: I have added index.html please see above